# OAuth doesn't work uncommenting the OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient() line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, visual-studio-2013, openid

I want to make my MVC4 web application log in using Google or Facebook. I've read that uncommenting the line `OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient()` of the AuthConfig.cs is enough to set it up but it doesn't work for me. The login page is still showing the advice "There are no external authentication services configured..." and the providers buttons don't appear.

Details:
- MVC 4 
- VS 2013 
- Using C#
- Using the internet aplication template

---------------------------------this is my AuthConfig.cs file------------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using Tarea3.Models;

namespace Tarea3
{
    public static class AuthConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterAuth()
        {
            // To let users of this site log in using their accounts from other sites such as Microsoft, Facebook, and Twitter,
            // you must update this site. For more information visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252166

            //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterTwitterClient(
            //    consumerKey: "",
            //    consumerSecret: "");

            //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
              //  appId: "",
                //appSecret: "");

            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Ask for more details, thanks!

Edited: I made a new project and it just works fine. But i dont know what im doing wrong in my main project. What are the reasons it could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are registering Auth in Global.asax (something like this: AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();)

Comment: Yes it is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Read the tutorial provided by Microsoft, please:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: If new project works fine, you need to find the difference. You could remove any dependency package, change global.asax.cs, make incompatible changes in web.config, remove required table from database. There are many reasons for it.